# SSRS - changing x-axis to show both date and hours of the day - issue

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2016, date-range, axis-labels

I am creating a timeline chart using the built in Range Bar Chart in SSRS (2016). I've managed to plot my datetime data on the chart showing the full duration of each process in chronological order.

However, I've tried numerous methods to get the x-axis to show both the date and all 24 hours in the day. so for example I want it to show 04/12/18 **just once** and the 00:00, 01:00 etc and continue onto the next day. The

Having googled around, I have tried changing interval type to day or hours in both horizontal axis properties and chart Axis options, but this didn't work. I also tried changing logarithmic scale to 1 but this didn't work. Any help would be appreciated. I'd like the axis to look like this but going over 24 hours and at some point show what date the 24 hours correspond to. http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_B35uCnDNR4M/TJIrhdygMQI/AAAAAAAADUs/yg0LX2ixpBM/s1600/19.JPG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Category Groups, add an expression that returns just the day. This should show the axis values on two lines, one for days the other for hours. I did a similar thing recently (not with a range chart though) where I need to show days and months. In my case the axis showed days closets to the base of the chart and months below the days but the month only shows once set of days.

[image]

This was the result of a very crude remake of that chart.. The highlighted numbers are the month numbers, the non-highlighted numbers are the days.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Alan Schofield. The problem I have is the date/time comes from one datetime field. Do you suggest I separate the date/time into 2 separate field?

Comment: Essentially yes, you could either do this in the dataset or just create an expression for the chart group, so rather than using `myDateTimeField` as the group you would have 2 expressions something like (from memory) `=CDate(Fields!myDateTimeField.Value)` and `=Hour(Fields!myDateTimeField.Value)` . Just check CDate only gives the date portion as I can't remember or check at the moment.